# referenceError: Can't find variable in react-native with fetch

Tags: react-native, fetch, victory-charts

hey im trying to make a chart using victory from the data online json data in react native. the code for the component is like below

```js
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  static navigationOption = {
    title: 'DashboardScreen'
  }

state = {
      getValue: '',
      dataSource:[],
      isLoading: true
    }


  componentDidMount() {
   
    const url = 'myurl';
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      })
    })
    .then((response)=> response.json() )
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson.Views)
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson,
        isLoading: false
      })
    })
    .catch((Error) => {
      console.log(Error)
    })


  }

  render() {
      return(
          <View style = {styles.container}>
              <VictoryChart minDomain={{ y: 0, x:0 }} width={350} theme={VictoryTheme.material}>
                <VictoryBar
                    style={{
                      data: { stroke: "#c43a31" },
                      parent: { border: "1px solid #ccc"}
                    }}
                    data={[
                      { x: 1, y: 1 },
                      { x: 2, y: dataSource[0].views},
                      { x: 3, y: dataSource[1].views},
                      { x: 4, y: dataSource[2].views},
                      { x: 5, y: dataSource[3].views}
                      ]}> 
                </VictoryBar>
              </VictoryChart>
          </View>
      )
  }
  }
```

i thought the fetch already make the json information an array in dataSource Variable and can be used as a data in victory but i always got error like referenceError: Can't find variable 'dataSource'

So, it would be very nice if anyone helps me out with this code and suggest how make the json data into chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
  data={[
                      { x: 1, y: 1 },
                      { x: 2, y: dataSource[0].views},
                      { x: 3, y: dataSource[1].views},
                      { x: 4, y: dataSource[2].views},
                      { x: 5, y: dataSource[3].views}
                      ]}>
```

to

```
  data={[
                      { x: 1, y: 1 },
                      { x: 2, y: this.state.dataSource[0].views},
                      { x: 3, y: this.state.dataSource[1].views},
                      { x: 4, y: this.state.dataSource[2].views},
                      { x: 5, y: this.state.dataSource[3].views}
                      ]}>
```

Hope this helps!